# VLC activex windowless mode not working

Tags: activex, z-index, vlc

The feature was added in version 2.0.6
see http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin

```
<object style="z-index:0;position:relative" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" 
        codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab" width="352" height="288" id="vlc">
<param name="Src" value="" />
<param name="windowless" value="True" />
</object>
<div style="width:50px;height:50px;position: absolute;z-index: 1000;background: green;top:0;left:0"></div>
```

The green div should be placed over the activex control, why is it not?.

Answer (score 0):

Your green square will appear at the top left hand corner of the screen.  You need to mess with the css to position it where your control appears.